# Convert varchar to time - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

Please see my code below, I want to convert the SmsStartTime to a time.

So result below needs to be **16:00:00.0000000**

```
DECLARE @SmsStartTime AS VARCHAR(2) = 16

--SELECT @SmsStartTime
SELECT CAST(@SmsStartTime AS TIME)
```

And result below needs to be **05:00:00.0000000**

```
DECLARE @SmsStartTime AS VARCHAR(2) = 5

--SELECT @SmsStartTime
SELECT CAST(@SmsStartTime AS TIME)
```

Comment: `SELECT CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, 16, 0) AS TIME)`

Comment: `DECLARE @SmsStartTime AS VARCHAR(2) = 16

SELECT CAST(@SmsStartTime + ':00:00' AS TIME)`

Comment: Above one will work thanks, please add it below as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
DECLARE @SmsStartTime AS VARCHAR(2) = 16 

SELECT CAST(@SmsStartTime + ':00:00' AS TIME)
```

**Result**

```
16:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (if you have SQL Server 2012):

```
DECLARE @SmsStartTime AS VARCHAR(2) = 5
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(@SmsStartTime,0,0,0,7)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx

Comment: You can use this function only on `sql server 2012` and its later version

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I wouldn't consider this an issue in 2016, when 2008 R2 is already out of mainstream support. There are already two newer major versions and another coming this year